# How to detect boundary points

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, point, area

I have a set of points in a 2D plane. I need to detect only the points that belong to the shape that borns from the union of this subset of points in order to cover the largest area: that is, the boundary points.

The following figure is an example:

[image: Set of points]

The red points are those ones I need to detect.

Comment: It looks like you want the convex hull.  That's well-defined and efficient algorithms exist for it, but first check that you never want the points to describe a concave shape -- in that case, the problem is not well-defined.

Comment: I.e., you want a convex hull. There are many algorithms for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is called [Convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). [A lot of algorithms exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) to calculate it.